# Database design for "shoutout" area

Tags: database-design

So currently I have a "post" where users can post messages like in facebook or twitter. However so far users are only able to view messages that they posted themselves.

This is the current table design

`ID | username | message | datetime`

However I have a "general" area where I want to display messages not only from the user themselves but from "friends" as well.

So far I haven't designed how "friendship" will be stored. I am thinking about creating individual tables for each user to store their friends although I don't know if this is a viable solution. Otherwise how should I go about designing a "friendship" relationship?

So my questions are,

1. How should I design a "friends" database relationship
2. How should I retrieve messages from all users that are friends with the currentuser?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no specific need to use a relational database, I suggest you think about using graph databases which are designed for and optimized for handling such cases where data can be directional (unidirectional such as likes and comments or bidirectional such as friendships).

I have no experience with those databases but your starting point (in terms of research) could be Neo4j which is a graph database that seems to be popular.

On the relational side you would need a `Friends` table with a PK user_id and an FK friend_id both related to your user table on your user_id field. You would need two entries per relationship (because friendship is bidirectional).

Answer (score 0):

My advice is not  to use 'username' in your posts table. String comparison is times slower than integer comparison. Store the 'user_id' instead.

In your 'friends' table store the following columns:

```
user_id | friend_id
```

Then to get the messages from the user and his friends you can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = your_users_id) OR user_id = your_users_id
```

This could be really simple depending on what language and/or framework you are using.

Good Luck!

Comment: _"String comparison is times slower than integer comparison."_ Do you have measurements for that?

Comment: @wolφi http://venublog.com/2010/04/20/int-and-string-data-comparison-difference-in-performance-because-of-quotes/

Comment: @wolφi This was the first post i found on google. I am not a database guy, but I remember reading an article with benchmark tests. Unfortunately I can't find it right now.

Comment: The venublog refers to something different (if you store numbers as strings, you should query them as strings not as numbers).

Comment: I'm seriously interested in the string vs int claim. I've heard it a number of times, but haven't seen measurements, so any data would be most appreciated!

Comment: @wolφi I dont have any measurements on hand, but in the data warehouse world this is common knowledge - number searching is always faster than a string search